# $USER environment variable is undefined when running script from crontab

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I've created a simple script to check the value of an environment variable when run from crontab:

```
#!bin/bash
echo $USER > cron.txt
```

I save this as `script.sh` in my home directory. If I run it manually, `cron.txt` contains my username, as I would expect.

I then add a line to my crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * ./script.sh
```

I again expect `cron.txt` to contain my username, but now it is just empty.

Why is `$USER` not defined when the script is run from crontab?

Comment: In what specific way does it not work when run (how?) from crontab (which?).

Comment: @Kusalananda crontab setting: `*/1 * * * * ./script.sh`  and output should shows my username in cron.txt file but it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the cron execute your job, it does so in an environment that is not the same as your current shell environment.

This means, for example, that `./script.sh` may not be found.

There are two solutions:

```
*/1 * * * * ( cd $HOME/mydir && ./script.sh )
```

or

```
*/1 * * * * $HOME/mydir/script.sh
```

I.e., specify exactly where the script may be found.

The first alternative may be preferable if you don't use absolute pathnames for the output file within the script.

If you go with the second option, modify your script so that you know where the output file goes:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$USER" >"$HOME/mydir/cron.txt"
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
( cd "$HOME/mydir" && echo "$USER" >cron.txt )
```

Notice that the `#!` line has to contain the correct absolute path to `bash` (your's was a relative path).

It should also be noted that cron on some Unices (Linux) do not set `USER` to the username of the user running the cron job. On these systems, use `$LOGNAME` instead, or set `USER` to `$LOGNAME` when invoking the script:

```
*/1 * * * * env USER=$LOGNAME $HOME/mydir/script.sh
```

Comment: script.sh is in home directory

Comment: @daisy In that case, just delete `mydir` from my examples. And also make sure it's executable and has the correct absolute path to `bash` on the `#!`-line (see answer).

Comment: path is also correct and permission has also given

Comment: @daisy If the `#!` is now correct (`#!/bin/bash`) and the script is executable, then it should work. I've tested it on my own machine.

Comment: okay. Let me do all steps again.

Comment: output is blank

Comment: @daisy Try with `$LOGNAME` instead of `$USER`. Apart from that, I don't really know what's wrong.

Comment: I have edited question with output, i think there should not be a space if file is blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53324/discussion-between-d-a-i-s-y-and-kusalananda).

Comment: The idea of using "env USER=$LOGNAME" seems to do the trick. (Ubuntu 18)